# A function that imports modules depending on the operating system

Tags: python, import, operating-system

I have written a script, that is supposed to run on different operating systems: my friends' computers and the university's server. The university's server is Linux, so there are few modules I cannot install because I have no sudo rights. (Side note: parts of my main script that call those modules (only post processing parts and not the ones who run computations) are commented for Linux). For this to work, I have created a python file named "functions.py" in which I have defined all my functions and also used conditional import of modules that are to be imported in the main file, as shown below:

```
def import_function_(Use_multiprocessing):

    import platform, cmath, math, os, shutil, subprocess as s

    if Use_multiprocessing:
        if platform.system()=='Linux':
            from multiprocessing import Process
            print("Your machine has "+platform.system()+" as an operating system, you can use threading by activating the variable Use_multiprocessing ")
        elif platform.system()!='Linux':
            import matlab.engine, numpy as n, ltspice
            from colorama import Fore, init
            init(autoreset=True)
            print(Fore.RED+"Your machine has "+platform.system()+" as an operating system, no threading can be used, sorry...")
    if __name__ != 'main':
        import functions as fct
```

However, when I run the main file, I get errors like "os not defined, numpy not defined..." and all the previously imported modules even if I am importing the function above...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The libraries are not defined since you they are only mentioned inside the function and not on module level.
I would suggest the following:

import_modules.py

```
import platform
import cmath
import math
import os
import shutil
import subprocess as s

if platform.system() == 'Linux':
    from multiprocessing import Process

    print(
        "Your machine has " + platform.system() + " as an operating system, you can use threading by activating the variable Use_multiprocessing ")
elif platform.system() != 'Linux':
    import numpy as n
    from colorama import Fore, init

    init(autoreset=True)
    print(
        Fore.RED + "Your machine has " + platform.system() + " as an operating system, no threading can be used, sorry...")
```

main.py

```
from import_modules import *
```

If there is really the need to separate the multiprocessing part put it into another file (import_modules_mp.py) and import this one if "Use_multiprocessing" is True.

PS: Nevertheless, it would be considered better practice to import the libraries in the module where you need the specific library. Don´t worry about performance. The imported libraries will be cached. Therefore, the import process will not executed multiple times.